# JavaFX Image drops on Y axis each time when added to the layout

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to add a bullet shooting function for a game. The bullet shoots, but every time the bullet is added to the scene it decreases on the Y axis.
My goal is to have the bullet be added to the layout at the same positions on the X and Y axis every time it is added.

I tried to do a check by using `if (!(layout.getChildren().contains(bullet))) {` but it still didn't work.

````java
public class AnimationTest {

static Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
static VBox layout = new VBox(10);

static Image image = new Image("/run-gun.png");
static Image bulletI = new Image("/bullet.png");
static ImageView bullet;

public static void main(String[] args){
}

public static void start() throws Exception {

imgView = new ImageView(image);
bullet = new ImageView(bulletI);

Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
    layout.getChildren().add(imgView);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
getKey(e);
});
}
public static void getKey(KeyEvent e){
bullet = new ImageView(bulletI);
if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE) {
        if (layout.getChildren().contains(bullet)) {

    } else {
        layout.getChildren().add(bullet);
        bullet.setTranslateX(imgView.getTranslateX() + 110);
        bullet.setTranslateY(imgView.getTranslateY() - 57.5);
        posY = (int) bullet.getTranslateY();
        bullet.setTranslateY(posY);

        // move bullet

        TranslateTransition tt = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(750), bullet);
        tt.setByX(1920);

        tt.setCycleCount(1);
        tt.setAutoReverse(false);

        tt.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                 try {
                     removeBullet();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

            }
            });
        tt.play();

    }

    } else {

    }
}
}

I want the bullet image to ALWAYS be added to the layout in the same X and Y positions. Thanks!


----- EDIT -----

```java
if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE) {
        if (layout.getChildren().contains(bullet)) {

    } else {
        layout.getChildren().add(bullet);
        bullet.setTranslateX(imgView.getTranslateX() + 110);
        bullet.setTranslateY(imgView.getTranslateY() - 57.5);

        // move bullet

        TranslateTransition tt = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(750), bullet);
        tt.setByX(1920);

        tt.setCycleCount(1);
        tt.setAutoReverse(false);

        tt.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                 try {
                     removeBullet();
                     bullet.setTranslateX(0);
                     bullet.setTranslateY(0);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

            }
            });
        tt.play();

    }

    } else {

    }
````

It still doesn't work, and I cant tell why.

Comment: `if (layout.getChildren().contains(bullet)) {` That check is completely unnecessary. You just created a new `ImageView` instance and assigned it to `bullet`. `ImageView` (or any of its supertypes does not override `equals` so reference equality is used to check, if the element is already in the list and none of the elements in the child list can be the same as `bullet`, since that instance was just created. The check always yields `false`.

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of absolute positioning it is not a good idea to use any kind of layout pane (like your HBox) because that will always interfere with your positioning. It is better to just use a Pane here which does not do any layout.

Comment: It's not 100% correct that `Pane` does not do any layout. It resizes the children to the preferred size, but it does not do any positioning...

Comment: Even that is not 1000% correct because it only applies to 'managed' children :-)  From the docs: "Pane resizes each managed child regardless of the child's visible property value; unmanaged children are ignored for all layout calculations." I normally use Panes with Shapes (which are not managed) but in this case of an ImageView it is of course true.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think is happening here?

```
bullet.setTranslateX(imgView.getTranslateX() + 110);
bullet.setTranslateY(imgView.getTranslateY() - 57.5);
```

As these values are never reset (set to 0.0 for example), they will just add up everytime.

Comment: I'll try resetting them to 0.0 once the bullet has finished moving. Will update later. Thanks

Comment: Please view the edited part of the post - I tried setting the TranslateX(); and TranslateY(); of the image bullet to 0 after the Translate Transition is finished, but it still does not work.

Comment: Did anything change at all? (if so, what did change?).

Comment: Why do you think those values accumulate? The `translateX/Y` properties are not updated in the code snippet posted, so the bullet's translate properties should always be the same.

Comment: @fabian they actually are, using the `TranslationTransition` further down the eventHandler code

Comment: That's for the bullet movement and it's not applied to `imgView`, but to `bullet`.

Comment: @mipa Since I used a VBox, I think the code was VBox layout = new VBox(10); wouldn’t that make ANY objects in the node automatically separated on the Y axis to a certain degree if you didn’t re-position them yourself?

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the late post but the answer was to use a Pane instead of a VBox. With a bit of extra position editing to re-adjust after trying to make up for using a VBox I finally made the gun shoot each bullet on the same Y position. Thanks to everyone that helped! :)